# How to make mod_wsgi use Python 3.9?

Tags: python, apache2, mod-wsgi

I originally had Python 3.6 installed and working well with WSGI and Apache2 on my Linux server.

Then I created a Flask app that had a dependency needing Python 3.7.
I've successfully (and I think) upgraded to Python 3.9.
Running

`python3` or `sudo python3`

both take me to Python 3.9. But then when I run

```sh
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-wsgi-py3
The following additional packages will be installed: python3, python3.6
```

it installs Python 3.6

After this, `python3` still points to Python 3.9. However, when the WSGI app is run, Python 3.6 is used, and it breaks. I have installed the Python package `mod-wsgi` with the correct PIP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to control which pytho is used via a simple configuration line. E.g. `/etc/httpd/conf.d/your_app.conf` with

```
WSGIPythonHome /opt/your_python_env
```

(I would advise to also set up an venv dedicated to your app if you aren't already doing so)

Comment: But the mod_wsgi doc said the version of python you are pointing via the above setting, should match the version which mod_wsgi is compiled against. So that should not work for chaning the python major/minor version. Am I right?

Comment: I'm also receiving `Invalid command 'WSGIPythonHome'` when I check for `apachectl -S`

Comment: @Saleh then in that case, how the command line gives python3.9 but Apache is using python3.8 - how can it be upgraded then (for Apache) because this affects the `pip install` pkgs, for testing i'm installing with `3.9` but for Apache I need to install it again for `3.8` ?! ... something doesn't make any sense. ( the 3.9 was installed with homebrew, while the system-wide python is in `/usr/bin`